# Matplotlib Color Palette

Tags: matplotlib

Is it possible to change what colors Matplotlib cycles through when it is generating its own colors for a graph's lines? I'm using the pylab module.

```
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.cm as cm

x=[1,2,3,4]
y=[5,6,7,8]

fig1 = Figure()

plot1 = fig1.add_subplot(311)
plot1.plot(x,y)

plot2 = fig1.add_subplot(312)
plot2.plot(x,y)

plot3 = fig1.add_subplot(313)
plot3.plot(x,y)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The colors are extracted from color maps. You can use [one of the predefined colormaps](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.colormaps), or [define your own](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/colors_api.html).

Unfortunately there is no way to use multiple colormaps per figure, you have to do it manually:

```
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.cm as cm

xval = pl.arange(0, 20, 0.2)

pl.subplot(311)
pl.plot(xval, pl.sin(xval), c=cm.summer(0))

pl.subplot(312)
pl.plot(xval, pl.cos(xval), c=cm.spring(0))

pl.subplot(313)
pl.plot(xval, pl.arctan(xval), xval, pl.fabs(xval))

pl.show()
```

[image]

Comment: How do you actually apply the colormap to the plot? I get errors if I apply it to the figure, a subplot etc... Is it an esoteric library module?

Comment: It's not esoteric at all, Matplotlib uses it all the time. What did you try?
There are many ways to apply a colormap: using the predefined methods in the `pyplot`/`pylab` module, using keyword arguments, or manually extracting colors by calling the colormap object.

Comment: Is there a way to set the figure to only pull colors from one of the colormaps?

Answer (score 25):

Yes, of course. Since it accept many kinds of color definition. It's easy to define your own color map. Here I just get colors from the colormap `hot`

```
import pylab as py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
a = np.arange(0,10)

py.figure()
for i in np.arange(10):
    c = cm.hot(i/10.,1)
    py.plot(a,i*a,color=c)

py.show()
```

[image]

Comment: So, I have a figure that contains three subplots. If I wanted to apply a colormap to one of the three subplots, I could say 'c=cm.hot' followed by 'a_plot.plot(x,y,color=c)'?

Comment: If you want to apply a whole colormap, use the `cmap` kwarg instead, or just select the colormap using `py.hot()`.

Comment: @Philipp, are you sure it will work ? I don't know how to use it with `plot`.

Comment: the `cmap` kwarg works for a few commands, but not with `plot`, that's right. Matplotlib seems to lack the `freezecolors` function, too.